# Выполнение скрипта при опреденной ширине экрана?

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы код выполнялся **только** при ширине экрана, меньше *992px*

[ссылка на codepen](http://codepen.io/olehsey/pen/zKdpRw)

```js
var toggle = $(".toggle");
    var menu = $(".menu");
    var link = $(".menu li");
    var wid = $(window).width();

    toggle.click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("on");
     menu.slideToggle();
     return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
     if(wid > 992 && $(".menu").is(":hidden")) {
      $(".menu").removeAttr("style");
      }
    });


    // ЭТОТ КОД ДОЛЖЕН ВЫПОЛНЯТСЯ ТОЛЬКО ПРИ ШИРИНЕ МЕНЬШЕ 992px !!!!
    $(document).click(function(e){
      if ($(e.target).closest(".menu").length) return;
      $('.menu').slideUp();
     toggle.removeClass("on");
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    link.click(function(){
     $(this).parent(".menu").slideUp();
     toggle.removeClass("on");
    });
    //
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a class="toggle" href="#"><span></span>menu</a>
    <ul class="menu clearfix">
     <li><a href="#test">item-1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">item-2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">item-3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать jQuery `.width()` и добавить `.resize()`, чтоб ловить изменения в ширине окна:

```
if ($(window).width() < 992) { menuHandler(); }

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        menuHandler();
    }
});

var menuHandler = function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest(".menu").length) return;
        $('.menu').slideUp();
        toggle.removeClass("on");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    link.click(function(){
        $(this).parent(".menu").slideUp();
        toggle.removeClass("on");
    });
}
```

Comment: такая конструкция работает, если ширина экрана при загрузке уже была меньше 992px, но если изначально была ширина больше и потом окно сузили, скрипт не работает, и наоборот, если при загрузке было < 992, а потом увеличиваем, то меню изчезает

Comment: тогда нужно комбинировать с `.resize()` - поправил код

Comment: `menuHandler()` продолжает выполняться при ресайзе экрана больше 992px, а все остальное работает как нужно

Comment: Спасибо, мне тоже пригодилось!!!

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужна именно ширина экрана устройства, то можно использовать **screen.width**.

Если нужна ширина окна браузера, то (без jQuery):

```
var width = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;
```

пример для ширины экрана:

```js
var toggle = $(".toggle");
var menu = $(".menu");
var link = $(".menu li");
var wid = $(window).width();

toggle.click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  menu.slideToggle();
  return false;
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  if (wid > 992 && $(".menu").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".menu").removeAttr("style");
  }
});


if (screen.width < 992) {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".menu").length) return;
    $('.menu').slideUp();
    toggle.removeClass("on");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  link.click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".menu").slideUp();
    toggle.removeClass("on");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="toggle" href="#"><span></span>menu</a>
<ul class="menu clearfix">
  <li><a href="#test">item-1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">item-2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">item-3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```